# DOCTYPE Emmet shortcut stopped working VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, hotkeys, emmet

!+tab+enter
shortcut for automatically filling DOCTYPE etc. in HTML document stopped all of a sudden.
I already reinstalled VS Code, checked JSON emmet settings, nothing works, google doesn't give answer either.
Other hotkeys work as usual. Any advices?
Thanks

upd. Code>preferences>settings> emmet> Show Suggestions As Snippets

Comment: I'm having the same problem. You can use `doc`, but that doesn't actually include the doctype...

Comment: hey , thanks for the answer! I actually did this in vscode: Code>preferences>settings> emmet> Show Suggestions As Snippets. It's a little different now as it shows a template of the snippet , but better than nothing